# Bot getting user identity from skype channel

Tags: botframework, identity, skype, cortana

For my bot all users are part of Azure AD. When chatting with Bot via Skype channel I assumed that bot would be able to get user identity from AD, but I've been reading that this is not true.

Is this possible at all for bot to know who the user is without going through auth process? How about grabbing workstation credentials with Cortana skill?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you won't be able to get AAD workstation credentials through Cortana; you'll have to incorporate an auth process at some point.

Cortana is only available with MSA accounts, and additionally only available in the [en-us market](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/faq) (see question: **What markets are supported and what is the timeline?**).